# How to select the first of many not disabled elements in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am writing an automation test that checks user's ability to schedule an appointment via the calendar. Some dates on the calendar are disabled (`aria-disabled="true"` ), some are enabled and available for selection (`aria-disabled="false"`). Depending on when the test is running, the disabled/enabled status of each date is going to change. How do I use Cypress to select the first date button that is not disabled?

Here's what the button's HTML look like, just in case:

```html
<button class="calendar-date" aria-label="Thursday July 28th, 2022" 
  aria-pressed="false" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" 
  type="button" data-datestring="ThuJul282022">
    28
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the buttons

- as a chained command

```js
cy.get('button.calendar-date')
  .filter('[aria-disabled="false"]')        // buttons not disabled
  .eq(0)                                    // first one
  .click()
```

- as part of the selector

```js
cy.get('button.calendar-date[aria-disabled="false"]')     // buttons not disabled
  .eq(0)                                                  // first one
  .click()
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use `:eq(0)` pseudo selector.

There was a `:first` as well, but it's now deprecated.

```js
cy.get('button.calendar-date[aria-disabled="false"]:eq(0)')
  .click();
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Fody's is to use [`.first()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/first#Syntax), which is just syntactic sugar for `.eq(0)`.

```js
cy.get('button.calendar-date[aria-disabled="false"]')
  .first()
  .click();
```